# Logic app getting 403 error while getting messages from DLQ of Service Bus in case of Particular Subscription

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

We have written logic app workflow to process message from DLQ of Service Bus Subscription. Its behavior is strange, as for one Subscription it is working fine but for other subscription in same topic it is giving below error

[image: Snapshot of error]

Below is the snapshot shot of topic properties

[image: Snapshot of Topic properties]

Below is the snapshot of Subscription overview, which clearly shows that auto forwarding is off and never enabled

[image: Subscription Overview]

To investigate it further, we tried the following

- Tried to receive messages in "Peek lock Mode" using Azure Function, but there its behavior is totally different, where it is not giving any error but returning message as null.
- Tried receiving using "Receive and Delete Mode" and now it was returning the message as null, but on other side it was deleting the message from DLQ as well.

As it is deleting a message from DLQ, so it means it processed the message, but some how message is coming as null.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

Received same error as you have:

[image]

And this is an expected behaviour when you enable like this:

[image]

**`Which is:`**

[image]

By clicking this, the trigger do not work and you cannot even peek messages in Service Bus. Create without clicking on this to make it work.

**`Without clicking on Forward messages to queue/topic it works:`**

[image]

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Sending Message:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering it, but as per details mentioned in question, we don't have any message forwarding applied to the subscription.

Comment: AFAIK, it only comes with that, there is no other way this can happen and I would suggest you to create a new subscription in that topic and try it.

Comment: yes, we would have created a new subscription with no issues, but in production subscription we are having few messages in DLQ and we need to process them.